Make image from text or more than two strings
I need to create an Image contend few strings like (first name, last name) with specific font.
Any kind of image extension acceptable like(.jpg, .png, ,.svg),
I'm using Laravel v9 and php:v8.0
like this
I tried base64decode to image
